# Matrix Convergence Series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ $\in$ $ \mathbb{R} ^{n×n}$ and consider the series:

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^{k}$$
Prove that the series converges iff all the eigenvalues of $A$ are strictly smaller than 1. Further, if the series converges, show that
$S$ is invertible with its inverse being $I − A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4+...+A^n\\ \to (I-A)S=\\I(I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4+...+A^n)-A(I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4+...+A^n)=\\I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4+...+A^n-(A+A^2+A^3+A^4+...+A^n+A^{n+1})=\\I-A^{n+1}$$
so now $n \to \infty ,|\lambda_i|<1 \to  $  we have  $  A^{n+1} \to 0$ 
$$(I-A)S=I-A^{n+1} \to I\\  (I-A)S=I \to S^{-1}=(I-A)\\$$

Comment: Thanks! Why does $A^{\infty}$ tend to zero. Can you make just that part a little more clear? @Khosrotash

Comment: Because you say :all the eigenvalues of A are strictly smaller than 1