# Convergence of a sequence of complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $A \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$ is a complex matrix such that the sequence $(A^p)_{p \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Denote
$$B_p = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{0 \le k \le p-1} A^k$$

How to prove that the sequence $(B^p)_{p \in \mathbb N}$ converges towards a matrix $B$ of a projector ?

*I'm able to notice that $B_p(I_n- A)= \frac{1}{p} (I_n-A^p)$ and therefore that the sequence $(B_p(I_n-A))_{p \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $0$... But not much more than that.*

Comment: hint : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043315/matrix-convergence-series/2043336#2043336

Comment: @Khosrotash Here $A$ can have eigenvalues of modulus equal to $1$.

Comment: I have an idea that I'll use tomorrow (for France), which is to use the Jordan canonical form of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is power-bounded. Therefore, all its eigenvalues have moduli $\le1$ and if $1$ is an eigenvalue, it must be semisimple. So, we can write $\mathbb R^n=V\oplus W$, where $V,W$ are invariant subspaces of $A$ and $V$ is the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ ($V=0$ if $1$ is not an eigenvalue).

So, $B_p|_V=id|_V$ (the identity map on $V$) and $B_p=\frac1p(id-A)^{-1}(I-A^p)$ on $W$. Take $p$ to infinity, we get $B_p\to id|_V$, i.e. $B_p$ converges to the projection map on $V$.